# Calendar Programmatically Created via Calendar API is not Visible in App by Default

Tags: android, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I am writing an app which takes events received from an API call and creates a new custom calendar via Google's Calendar API, and then adds the adds/deletes/updates the events with the calendar as needed. This all works very well. The problem I am running into is that the custom calendar is not visible in the Android Google Calendar app by default after it's created. The user has to Refresh then Settings >>> Show More (under the appropriate Google account >>> Select the Calendar By Name >>> Manually select the Sync switch before they can see the calendar and events the app created. I am concerned that many users may not know that they need to do these additional steps to make the calendar appear within the Calendar app.

Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

I don't see any methods in the Calendar API docs which allow me to programmatically set my created calendar to sync/be visible. Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Calender Provider API can be used by applications and sync adapters. The rules vary depending on what type of program is making the calls. This document focuses primarily on using the Calendar Provider API as an application.

Through the Calendar Provider API, applications and sync adapters can get read/write access to the database tables that hold a user's calendar data.

A sync adapter synchronizes the calendar data on a user's device with another server or data source. In the [CalendarContract.Calendars](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html) and [CalendarContract.Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/pr) tables, there are columns that are reserved for the sync adapters to use. The provider and applications should not modify them. In fact, they are not visible unless they are accessed as a sync adapter.

To read calendar data, an application must include the `READ_CALENDAR` permission in its manifest file. It must include the `WRITE_CALENDAR` permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"...>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
...
</manifest>
```

Here is a helper method you can use to return a URI for use with a sync adapter:

```
static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
return uri.buildUpon()
.appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true")
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
.appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();
}
```

For a sample implementation of a sync adapter, see SampleSyncAdapter: https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html